# PyQT Fullscreen Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

Ok, so still fairly new to python, ans just started to use PyQT on my Pi to make a GUI for some code I have. However, the window opens for a split second and closes to a small window. Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class mainUI(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
                super(mainUI, self).__init__()
                self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):

                MainWindow = QtGui.QWidget()
                MainWindow.showFullScreen()
                MainWindow.setWindowTitle('TimeBot')
                MainWindow.show()

                qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit')
                qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit)
                qbtn.move(5,5)
                qbtn.show()

                self.show()            

def main():
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

        window = mainUI()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: I was going to link the zetcode tutorial, when I noticed it contained the same bug you have!

Comment: @hackyday: People make this mistake ALL the time.

Comment: @Spook811: In general, remove EVERYTHING you don't absolutely need in your minimal working examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that inside `initUi` you make another `QWidget`, set it to full screen, show it, and then when that widget goes out of scope it gets garbage collected and disappears. You meant to use `self` instead of making a new `QWidget`. Like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class mainUI(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainUI, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.showFullScreen()
        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit')
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit)
        qbtn.move(5,5)
        self.button = qbtn
        qbtn.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = mainUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that I keep a reference to `qbtn` so that it doesn't get garbage collected and disappear.

Answer (score 0):

`self.showMaximized()`

PyQt5 is a Python binding of the Qt toolkit. For QtWidgets there is full documentation.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showMaximized

For another show*() methods just take a look into documentation, it's complete, nice. And probably it's the most well-documented C++ framework in the world.